# How to check if one string ends with another, or the other way around?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Given two strings, return True if either of the strings appears at the very end of the other string, ignoring upper/lower case differences (in other words, the computation should not be "case sensitive").

Examples / Tests:

```
>>> end_other('Hiabc', 'abc') 
True 
>>> end_other('AbC', 'HiaBc') 
True 
>>> end_other('abc', 'abXabc') 
True
```

My Code:

```
def end_other(s1, s2):
    
    s1 = s1.upper()
    s2 = s2.upper()
    
    if s1[2:6] == s2:
        return True
    elif s2[2:6] == s1:
        return True
    elif s2 == s1:
        return True    
    else:
        return False
```

What I expect is wrong.

(NB: this is a code practice from [CodingBat](https://codingbat.com/prob/p174314)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any reason you can't use the built-in functions?

```
def end_other(s1, s2):
    s1 = s1.upper()
    s2 = s2.upper()
    return s1.endswith(s2) or s2.endswith(s1)
```

Your code with the arbitrary slices doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

something like this, using `str.rfind()`:

```
In [114]: def end(s1,s2):
    s1=s1.lower()
    s2=s2.lower()
    if s1 in s2 and s2.rfind(s1)+len(s1) == len(s2):
        return True
    elif  s2 in s1 and s1.rfind(s2)+len(s2) == len(s1):
        return True 
    return False
   .....: 

In [115]: end('Hiabc','abc')
Out[115]: True

In [116]: end('abC','HiaBc')
Out[116]: True

In [117]: end('abc','abxabc')
Out[117]: True

In [118]: end('abc','bc')
Out[118]: True

In [119]: end('ab','ab12')
Out[119]: False
```